# Passing a pointer by reference crashes the programme

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to create a class with memory allocated during an object initialisation (using `init` procedure). The programme crashes with `segfault` at runtime. As I have found out, this is caused because I pass the pointer by reference `**sequence`. Even if I allocate memory before procedure call, the segfault takes place. And once I pass the pointer as a pure value `*sequence` the fault is gone. Cannot I pass pointers by reference?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

typedef struct
{
    int *sequence;
} set;

void init(int **sequence, unsigned amount, ...)
{    
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, amount);

    *sequence = malloc(amount * sizeof(**sequence));

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < amount; i++)
        *sequence[i] = va_arg(args, int);
    
    va_end(args);
}

int main(void)
{
    set x;   
    init(&x.sequence, 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4);

    for (char i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        printf("%u\t", x.sequence[i]);
}
```

Comment: `*sequence[i] = va_arg(args, int);` --> should be `(*sequence)[i] = va_arg(args, int);`

Comment: @AlexLop. Shame on me, thanks. Didn't expect the issue to be caused by the precedence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
*sequence[i] = va_arg(args, int);
```

to this:

```
(*sequence)[i] = va_arg(args, int);
```

The `[]` operator binds more tightly than `*`, so parentheses are needed to obtain the desired grouping.

Comment: Didn't really expect this. It usually worked when I wrote `*var[]`

Comment: This particular case could never work without the parentheses (except when `i` is zero).  The difference is you have an array of ints rather than an array of pointers.  That means you need to get it down to an `int *` before you can attempt to index into it.

Comment: Feel so ashamed :c Anyway, thanks, wait for acceptance

Comment: It's an easy mistake to make - you're in good company!